# Using on UnitTest Mock-DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-testing, mocking

In my C# Project I had a query with a `.ToList();` at the end:

```
public List<Product> ListAllProducts()
{
    List<Product> products = db.Products
        .Where(...)
        .Select(p => new Product()
        {
            ProductId = p.ProductId,
            ...
        })
        .ToList();

    return products;
}
```

From time to time, I was getting a `EntityException: "The underlying provider failed on Open."` error. I made the following work-around based on answers I found here on SO

```
public List<Product> ListAllProducts()
{
    try
    {
        // When accessing a lot of Database Rows the following error might occur:
        // EntityException: "The underlying provider failed on Open." With an inner TimeoutExpiredException.
        // So, we use a new db so it's less likely to occur
        using(MyDbContext usingDb = new MyDbContext())
        {
            // and also set the CommandTimeout to 2 min, instead of the default 30 sec, just in case
            ((IObjectContextAdapter)usingDb).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 120;

            List<Product> products = usingDb.Products
                .Where(...)
                .Select(p => new Product()
                {
                    ProductId = p.ProductId,
                    ...
                })
                .ToList();

            return products;
        }
    }
    // and also have a try-catch in case the error stil occurres,
    // since we don't want the entire website to crash
    catch (EntityException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An error has occured: " + ex.StackTrace);
        return new List<Product>();
    }
}
```

So far it seems to work and I receive my data every time (and just in case I also added the try-catch).

Now I'm UnitTesting and I'm facing a problem. I have a `MockDbContext` in my UnitTest, but since I'm using the `using(...)` which uses the non-Mock version, my UnitTests fail. How am I able to test this using the MockDbContext instead of the default one?

---

EDIT:

I just came across [this post about UnitTesting Mock DbContext](http://romiller.com/2012/02/14/testing-with-a-fake-dbcontext/). So it seems to me I do indeed need to pass it all the way to my method, or just don't use the `using(MyDbContext usingDb = new MyDbContext())` and instead only temporarily increase the CommandTimeout and use the try-catch. Is there really no other way? Or is there a better fix / workaround for the error I'm getting, without the `using(MyDbContext usingDb = new MyDbContext())` all together?

---

EDIT 2:

To make my situation more clear:

I have MyDbContext-class and a IMyDbContext-interface.

I have the following in each of my Controllers:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private IMyDbContext _db;

    public ProductController(IMyDbContext db)
    {
        this._db = db;
    }

    ... // Methods that use this "_db"

    public List<Product> ListAllProducts()
    {
        try
        {
            using(MyDbContext usingDb = new MyDbContext())
            {
                ... // Query that uses "usingDb"
            }
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

In my normal code I create the instance like this:

```
ProductController controller = new ProductController(new MyDbContext());
```

In my UnitTest code I create the instance like this:

```
ProductController controller = new ProductController(this.GetTestDb());

// With GetTestDb something like this:
private IMyDbContext GetTestDb()
{
    var memoryProducts = new Product { ... };
    ...

    var mockDB = new Mock<FakeMyDbContext>();
    mockDb.Setup(m => m.Products).Returns(memoryProducts);
    ...
    return mockDB.Object;
}
```

Everything works great, both in my normal project as my UnitTest, except for this `using(MyDbContext usingDb = new MyDbContext())` part in the ListAll-methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is desirable to factor code to facilitate testing, having code branches that are only executed within a test doesn't help. Really what this does is place test environment configuration code into your live code.

What's you need is one more bit of abstraction for the creation of the `DbContext`. You should pass in a delegate that constructs the `DbContext`:

```
public List<Product> ListAllProducts(Func<DbContext> dbFunc)
{
    using(MyDbContext usingDb = dbFunc())
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And now that you are no longer passing around a heavy `DbContext` object, you can re-factor the method parameter into the class constructor.

```
public class ProductDAL
{
    private Func<DbContext> _dbFunc;

    public ProductDAL(Func<DbContext> dbFunc)
    {
        _dbFunc = dbFunc;
    }

    public List<Product> ListAllProducts()
    {
        using(MyDbContext usingDb = _dbFunc())
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

And the cherry on top is that you can now control which `DbContext` to use, including the connection string pulled from a config file, all the way out in your IOC container and never worry about it anywhere else in the code.

Comment: Using the delegate looks similar in using an interface which I have right now. I have a `MyDbContext`-class and `IMyDbContext`-interface and in my ProductController I use: `private IMyDbContext db; public ProductController(IMyDbContext _db){ this.db = _db; }` Should I change this to a delegate instead? It looks to be able to solve my problem, but I want to make sure before changing it EVERYWHERE in my code.

Comment: Yes, you should change it to a delegate. The reason is that you want your `DbContext`s to be short-lived.

Comment: Ok thanks, then I will do that tomorrow for all Controllers. I will accept your answer as soon as everything works when using the delegate. It looks very promising.

Comment: One other note, if you change it to Func<IMyDbContext> then you will either have to inherit IDisposable in IMyDbContext, or you will have to cast the return value of the Func to (IDisposable) within the using statement. Both of these are less-than optimal and the better alternative becomes to encapsulate the delegate in a builder-type class that itself is disposable and disposes the DbContext as it is being disposed.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it is difficult to get proper unit testing without structuring the code to be unit-test-friendly, but you could try making the class generic so it could be instantiated with either context.

```
public class SomeClass<T> where T: MyDbContext, new()
{
    public List<Product> ListAllProducts()
    {
        using(MyDbContext usingDb = new T())
        {
            ((IObjectContextAdapter)usingDb).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 120;
            List<Product> products = usingDb.Products.ToList();
            return products;
        }
    }
}


// real-code:
var foo = new SomeClass<MyDbContext>();

// test
var bar = new SomeClass<MockContext>();
```